# sqlite3 python query needed for quiz isn't working

Tags: python, sqlite

For my school project I decided to make a physics revision tool. The tool lets users log in and saves information about their performance on certain questions. As a result of this I realised I needed to name each table used to store each individual users scores so I thought using .format would be appropriate. It seemed to be working fine until the point where i needed to add code that would add information to the table. From the testing i have done on the code so far, i think the problem is because i am using .format it won't actually create any columns. I don't know how to get around that please help. Appropriate sections of code have been provided:

```
def quesprep():
intro.destroy()
con= sqlite3.connect("login.db")
c= con.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT accid FROM credentials WHERE accountname = ?", (user,))
global results
results=c.fetchall()
con.commit()
con.close()
con= sqlite3.connect("store.db")
c= con.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(mod integer, ques integer,score integer)""".format(results))
c.execute("INSERT INTO {} Values(mod=2,ques=1, score=0)".format(results))
con.commit()
con.close()
ques()


def mod2q1page():
questionspage.destroy()
con= sqlite3.connect("login.db")
c= con.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT accid FROM credentials WHERE accountname = ?", (user,))
global results
results=c.fetchall()
con.commit()
con= sqlite3.connect("store.db")
c= con.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {} VALUES(mod=2, ques=2, score=0)" .format(results))
```

Comment: Don't post code as image

Comment: Hi, I see you are new on StackOverflow. You should paste any code as text preceded with four spaces in the beginning of every line. Could you edit your question?

Comment: sorry, i wasn't aware of how i should add code.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be several things wrong here.

Format takes a variable inside the {} ... like {0}, {1} etc

Placeholders are the preferred route to take with formatting sql queries ... like you did in your SELECT

I am not sure what the issue is here but if you are trying to add columns, you need to ALTER the table ... not INSERT.  INSERT will add a row item.  If you can post the error, perhaps we can help a little more.  To start you out though, try placeholders in lieu of format.

Also, fetchall returns a list of tuples ... need to send a tuple in sql, not a list.

```
for x in results:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO ? (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2, 3);", x)
```

Edit:

I stand corrected - I ran this code:

```
    data = [('user',)]
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ? (id, email, password) VALUES (1, test, test);", data)
```

syntax error because you cannot add placeholder to table name. Read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

I used format with the {0}:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {0} (id, email, password) VALUES (1, test, test);".format('user'))
```

The query was successful.  I believe that is your problem here.

Comment: The problem is that when i initially create the table using .format it won't actually ceate the specified coloumns, I tried your solutions and they didin't seem to work.

Comment: the error code I get when i get to the part of the code where i tey to insert values into the table is:  File "C:\Users\Sipho\Documents\Physics revision tool V1.1.py", line 455, in mod2q1page
    c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {} VALUES(mod=2, ques=1, score=0)".format(results,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: mod

Comment: Please see this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47458239/957944)

Essentially you need to wrap your strings in 'string' else it is interpreted as a column name.

Comment: Here is some code for you:  results = 'users'
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (2, 'test', 'test');")
    conn.commit()

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
intro.destroy()
con= sqlite3.connect("login.db")
c= con.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT accountname FROM credentials WHERE accountname = ?", (user,))
results=c.fetchone()
global tablename
tablename=" ".join(map(str, (results)))
con.commit()
con.close()
global m
m="mod"
global q
q="ques"
global s
s="score"
fieldtype="INTEGER"
con=sqlite3.connect("store.db")
c=con.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ({fc} {ft}, {sc} {ft2}, {tc} {ft3})'\
          .format(tablename, fc=m, ft=fieldtype, sc=q, ft2=fieldtype, tc=s, 
ft3=fieldtype))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```